# How to return from previous fragment after activity is destroyed

Tags: android, fragment, android-fragmentactivity

I have activity A which has bottom navigation with four fragments, the 4th fragment needs authentication, so if not authenticated I will be redirected to login activity, when I pressed back button from login activity, it directly opens the first fragment not the last opened fragment.

```
case R.id.account:
                if (isLoggedIn()) {
                    getSupportFragmentManager()
                            .beginTransaction()
                            .add(R.id.fragment_container, new AccounFragment())
                            .commit();
                } else {
                   goTologInActivity();
                }
                break;
```

Comment: First fragment as in first fragment from the activity A's bottom navigation?

Comment: yes @ParagPawar

Comment: Ummm, Okay there is a way to open the last fragment, but don't you think if the last fragment is opened then it will check for authentication and again will go back to Login activity? It could be an endless loop resulting in app to crash.

Comment: Usually, if you press the back button from Login screen it should close the app, but depending upon your use case it might be different but can you explain what do you want exactly and why?

Comment: you should be managing this with help of nav graph from android architecture components